# Installed create-react-app and not able to change folder structure

Tags: linux, reactjs, file, ubuntu

After installing create-react app I want to modify my files.
Despite various attempts I am not able to delete various files properly and can't modify folder structure of my react app.

Changed its folder permission to chmod 777.

Error shown in visual studio is :

```
Error : EPREM : operation not permitted, unlink '/home/user/Documents/react-app/src/App.css'
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `ll /home/user/Documents/react-app/src`?

Comment: here is the output : 
drwxrwxrwx   6 root  root    4096

Comment: Have you tried just using `/bin/rm` to remove the file? Are you logged into the computer as you're own user account or as root?